# What can be the cause of a sudden explosion in the loss when training a UNet

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation

The loss function had a sudden explosion when i trained the UNet Model.i only use Monai's BasicUNet.The loss function is combine dice_loss and bce_loss.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqBdQ.png)

Comment: I guess this can happen for a lot of reasons. Sometimes training can be unstable if the network produces large absolute values. So if you can compute min/max/mean of the outputs of the downsampling and upsampling blocks in the network this could be one thing to check. Are you normalizing your inputs properly?

Comment: Thank you, Chillston. I got some inspiration by your thoughts. i sloved the problems. It seems to be related to my normalatzation.I use $frac{data - mean(data)} {std(data)}$,but the data is a single data. I made the fool mistake.